# How to analyse .NET Core web app memory dump from Azure Kudu?

Tags: azure, memory-leaks, .net-core

I have a memory leak inside an Azure web app. The application runs .NET Core. I'm trying to analyse a memory dump to test my hypothesis about what is leaking.

I collected a memory dump using Kudu - I went to `Tools > Support > Metrics > Diagnose` to trigger the dump, then into the `Diagnostics` tab and could download both the raw `.dmp` file as well as the analysis results that Kudu auto-generated from DebugDiag. However, the analysis results file has no actual results in it, and lists this error message:

```
CLR is loaded in the target, but the correct dac file cannot be found
```

I also downloaded the raw `.dmp` file and tried to analyse that through DebugDiag locally, as well as in Visual Studio 2015's memory dump analyser. In all cases I'm not able to see any actual memory analysis.

When I tried this against another app, running against the full .NET Framework v4.6, the DebugDiag analysis worked. So I'm suspicious that the problem I'm experiencing is because the app runs against .NET Core.

Are there any memory dump analysers that work with .NET Core? Or, is there a trick to getting .NET Core dumps to work with DebugDiag's `DotNetMemoryAnalysis` rules?

Comment: Did you try it in VS 2017?

Comment: Yes I did. It still won't work - it shows an option called `Debug with Native Only` but nothing about debugging managed memory.

Comment: On stackoverflow You can find articles, that "Debug with Native Only" is enabled only for enterprise version;

Comment: Thanks @LatvianMarksman - I am using the Enterprise edition. I'm not sure what you're meaning though - this isn't the feature that I actually want. I want to debug managed code/memory from a .NET Core app.